# How to remove session variable in a template after it's job is done in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-3.4, django-sessions

I have a app called `dashboard` which is where I redirect all logged in users with an option to add articles by the user.

After the user hits Submit button in the form, the data is sent to `/dashboard/article/save` URL via POST and after the data is stored, the view returns `HttpResponseRedirect` to `show_dashboard` which renders `dashboard.html` with a session variable `result`.

In the dashboard template file, I have added a notify.js code to show acknowledgements to user. The problem is if this session var is defined, everytime the dashboard page is showed, the notification is triggered EVEN if the user didn't add an article.

(I'm new to using web frameworks so I do not know how this all works properly)

Some code:

**dashboard/models.py:**

```
class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ar_title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ar_data = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def getArticleTitle(self):
        return self.title

    def getArticleData(self):
        return self.title

    def getArticleAuthor(self):
        return self.user
```

**dashboard/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.show_dashboard,name='home_dashboard'),
    url(r'^profile/save/', views.save_profile,name="save_profile"),
    url(r'^newsfeed/', views.get_newsfeed,name="newsfeed",),
    url(r'^profile/', views.show_profile,name="show_profile"),
    url(r'^article/save/', views.add_new_article,name="add_new_article"),
]
```

**dashboard/views.py:**

```
@login_required
def show_dashboard(request):
    return render(request,'dashboard/dashboard.html',{'form':NewArticleForm()})

def add_new_article(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        ar_title= request.POST['ar_title']
        ar_data = request.POST['ar_data']
        user = request.user
        form = NewArticleForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            Article.objects.create(ar_title=ar_title,ar_data=ar_data,user=user)
            request.session["result"] = "add_article_OK"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_dashboard'))
```

**dashboard.html:**

```
{% ifequal request.session.result 'add_article_OK' %}
    <script>
        $.notify("New article added successfully", 
            {position:"bottom right","className":"success","autoHide":"yes","autoHideDelay":"3000"});
    </script>
{% endifequal %}
```

Now, how do I remove this session value after it has displayed the message? I know `del request.session['result']` can be issued but where can I put it in this heirarchy of moves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in the `show_dashboard` view.

Instead of getting the value from the session in the template, pop it in the view and pass it to the template; that way you take care of getting and clearing it in one go.

```
@login_required
def show_dashboard(request):
    context = {
        'form': NewArticleForm(),
        'result': request.session.pop('result', None)
    }
    return render(request,'dashboard/dashboard.html',context)

...
{% ifequal result 'add_article_OK' %}
```